# how to do after auto submit

Tags: parameters, submit

I want to log to some site automaticly
so I used this code and it worked

```
<form id="myform" runat="server" action="http://my.yad2.co.il/login.php">
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="MyUserName" name="Username" id="login_email" />
        <br />
        <input type="password" name="Password" id="Irealpass" value="MyPassword" />
        <script>
            document.forms["myform"].submit();
        </script>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now I want to pass the parameters without using text boxes.
I replaced the script with this script

```
    <script>
    var params = { Username: "MyUserName", Password: "MyPassword" };
            this.getForm().getEl().dom.action = 
            'http://my.yad2.co.il/login.php"?' + Ext.urlEncode(params);
            document.forms["myform"].submit();
    </script>
```

Why it dosent work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace the action attribute you can use the following code

```
document.forms["myform"].action='http://my.yad2.co.il/login.php?' + Ext.urlEncode(params)
```

However the server must not accept login/password from query string since you are passing them in a post request.

I would suggest setting textbox values before submitting

```
<form id="myform" runat="server" action="http://my.yad2.co.il/login.php">
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="MyUserName" name="Username" id="login_email" />
            <br />
            <input type="password" name="Password" id="Irealpass" value="MyPassword" />
                <script>
                Ext.get("login_email").set({value:"MyUserName1"});
                Ext.get("Irealpass").set({value:"MyPassword1"});

                document.forms["myform"].submit();
                </script>

        </div>
    </form>
```